# How to set Sticky or fixed on scroll- Mega Menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this Mega Menu code:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/YXBeLJ)

```
'https://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/YXBeLJ'
```

This is a small example for the menu html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                Home
            </a>
        </li>  
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
                Link 1
            </a>
            <div class="contact"></div>
        </li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block">|||</a>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here the javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('.toggle-menu').click(function(){
    $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');      
  });
});
```

But this menu is fixed, I want it stuck at top on scroll

Comment: Please include a text-based [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox is it enough right now?

Comment: Not really. Without going into the codepen I cannot replicate the issue you’re seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can help, I add the "Fixed" class on scroll event. add some CSS to fix the header.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
          var sticky = $('.content'),
              scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

          if (scroll >= 50) sticky.addClass('fixed');
          else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
        });
    });
```

```css
 body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 300 14px/18px Roboto;
    background-image: url('../images/texture.png');
 }
  

 *,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a, a:hover, a.active, a:active, a:visited, a:focus{
    color:#fefefe;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.content{
    max-width: 1700px;
        margin: 50px auto;
}

.exo-menu{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background: #23364B;
}
.exo-menu > li {    display: inline-block;float:left;}
.exo-menu > li > a{
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1px #365670 dotted;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.exo-menu > li > a.active,
.exo-menu > li > a:hover,
li.drop-down ul > li > a:hover{
    background:#009FE1;
    color:#fff;
}
.exo-menu i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
li.drop-down,
.flyout-right,
.flyout-left{position:relative;}
li.drop-down:before {
  content: "\f103";
  color: #fff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li.drop-down>ul{
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 230px;

}
.drop-down-ul{display:none;}
.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul{
  top: 0;
  min-width: 230px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #365670;
  }

li.drop-down>ul>li>a,
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #365670;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #547787;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
}
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #B8C7BC;
}


/*Flyout Mega*/
.flyout-mega-wrap {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    min-width: 742px;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color:#eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
.flyout-mega ul > li > a {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
}
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:hover,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:active,
.flyout-mega ul > li > a:focus{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #ccc !important
}
/*mega menu*/

.mega-menu {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  display:none;
  padding-top: 0;
  min-height: 100%;

}
h4.row.mega-title {
  color: #eee;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #547787;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #365670
  }
 .mega-menu ul li a {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 90%;
  display: block;
}
ul.stander li a {
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

ul.description li {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    line-height: 8px;
}

ul.description li span {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 85%;
}
a.view-more{
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background-color: #009FE1;
  padding: 2px 10px !important;
  line-height: 21px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
a.view-more:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#0DADEF;
}
ul.icon-des li a i {
    color: #fff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009FE1;
    line-height: 35px !important;
}

ul.icon-des li {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
/*Blog DropDown*/
.Blog{
    left:0;
    display:none;
    color:#fefefe;
    padding-top:15px;
    background:#547787;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Blog .blog-title{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;

}
.Blog .blog-des{
    color:#ccc;
    font-size:90%;
    margin-top:15px;
}
.Blog a.view-more{
    margin-top:0px;
}
/*Images*/
.Images{
    left:0;
   width:100%;
     display:none;
    color:#fefefe;
    padding-top:15px;
    background:#547787;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.Images h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*common*/
.flyout-right ul>li>a ,
.flyout-left ul>li>a,
.flyout-mega-wrap,
.mega-menu{
    background-color: #547787;
}

/*hover*/
.Blog:hover,
.Images:hover,
.mega-menu:hover,
.drop-down-ul:hover,
li.flyout-left>ul:hover,
li.flyout-right>ul:hover,
.flyout-mega-wrap:hover,
li.flyout-left a:hover +ul,
li.flyout-right a:hover +ul,
.blog-drop-down >a:hover+.Blog,
li.drop-down>a:hover +.drop-down-ul,
.images-drop-down>a:hover +.Images,
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
li.flyout-mega>a:hover +.flyout-mega-wrap{
    display:block;
}
/*responsive*/
 @media (min-width:767px){
    .exo-menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    padding: 20px 22px;
 }
.mega-menu, .flyout-mega-wrap, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
        position:absolute;
}
 .flyout-right>ul{
    left: 100%;
    }
    .flyout-left>ul{
    right: 100%;
}
 }
@media (max-width:767px){

    .exo-menu {
        min-height: 58px;
        background-color: #23364B;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .exo-menu > li > a{
        width:100% ;
        display:none ;
    
    }
    .exo-menu > li{
        width:100%;
    }
    .display.exo-menu > li > a{
      display:block ;
        padding: 20px 22px;
    }
    
.mega-menu, .Images, .Blog,.flyout-right>ul,
.flyout-left>ul, li.drop-down>ul{
        position:relative;
}

}
a.toggle-menu{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 27px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #23364B;
    top: 0px;
}

.content.fixed {
        right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:25px;marin-bottom:15px;font-weight:bold;texxxt-decoration:none; color:#484848;">
    <a style="color:#000;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/arjunamgain/" target="_blank">My Profile</a>
</div>


 
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<body class="background">
     <div class="content">
     
        <ul class="exo-menu">
            <li><a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Flyout</a>
                <!--Drop Down-->
                <ul class="drop-down-ul animated fadeIn">
                <li class="flyout-right"><a href="#">Flyout Right</a><!--Flyout Right-->
                    <ul class="animated fadeIn">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li class="flyout-left"><a href="#">Flyout Left</a><!--Flyout Left-->
                    <ul class="animated fadeIn">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                    </ul>           
                </li>
                
                <li><a href="#">No Flyout</a></li>
                 
                </ul>
                <!--//End drop down-->
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Mega Menu</a>
                <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
                    <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h4 class="row mega-title">Feature</h4>
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rUk36pd-LbM/VcLb48X4f-I/AAAAAAAAGCI/Y_UxBAgEqwA/s1600/Magento_themes.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <h4 class="row mega-title">Standers</h4>
                                <ul class="stander">
                                    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Computer</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">laptop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Camera</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">I pad</a></li>
                                    <li><a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">View more</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h4 class="row mega-title">Description</h4>
                                <ul class="description">
                                    <li><a href="#">Women</a>
                                        <span>Description of Women</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Men</a>
                                            <span>Description of men Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kids</a>
                                            <span>Description of Kids Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Others</a>
                                            <span>Description of Others Cloths</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                    <a class="view-more btn btn-sm " href="#">View more</a>
                                             
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h4 class="row mega-title">Icon + Description</h4>
                                <ul class="icon-des">
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Web</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Mobile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i>Responsive</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Desktop</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>UI/UX</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="blog-drop-down"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Blog</a>
                <div class="Blog animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VG_e0pKfrDo/VcLb6JwZqfI/AAAAAAAAGCk/8ZgA9kZqTQ8/s1600/images3.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                    <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                            <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hUt5FrdZHio/VcLb5dlwTBI/AAAAAAAAGCU/UUH5N1JkoQc/s1600/images1.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                        <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                                    <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A7U1uPlSq6Y/VcLb5kKHCkI/AAAAAAAAGCc/7WghyndTEuY/s1600/images2.jpg">
                        <div class="blog-des">
                        <h4 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod 
                            tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
                            nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. </p>
                                    <a class="view-more btn- btn-sm" href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     
                    
                </div>
            </li>
            <li  class="images-drop-down"><a  href="#"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i> Images</a>
                <div class="Images animated fadeIn">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VG_e0pKfrDo/VcLb6JwZqfI/AAAAAAAAGCk/8ZgA9kZqTQ8/s1600/images3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hUt5FrdZHio/VcLb5dlwTBI/AAAAAAAAGCU/UUH5N1JkoQc/s1600/images1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A7U1uPlSq6Y/VcLb5kKHCkI/AAAAAAAAGCc/7WghyndTEuY/s1600/images2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h4>Images Title </h4>
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hGrnZIjzL2k/VcLb47kyQKI/AAAAAAAAGCQ/J6Q2IAHIQvQ/s1600/image4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a>
                <div class="contact">
            
                </div>
            </li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle-menu visible-xs-block">|||</a>        
    </ul>
     
     
     </div>
     <section style="height:100vh"></section>
         <section style="height:100vh"></section>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is what i am looked for, Sure i will style my header